# Getting a "Cannot read property 'myVar' of undefined" that I can't resolve even with typeof

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
myWord = ''

db.collection('testCollection', function (err, collection) {
    collection.find({room:"room1"}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        if(typeof results[0].word === "undefined")
            myWord = '';
        else
            myWord = results[0].word;
    });
});
```

I'm using socket.io, express, and the mongodb native driver.

The database is 100% empty when this query executes. Every time it hits the line:

```
if(typeof results[0].word === "undefined")
```

I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'word' of undefined
```

I'm new to mongodb and nodejs, so I might even be structuring my code wrong. If you need to see more code, of course let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `if(results[0] === undefined)` or `if(typeof results[0] == "undefined")`

You're trying to take the type of what you get after dereferencing, when it's the dereferencing of a null value that's breaking it in the first place.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for your help. Worked perfectly. Makes complete sense now that I see it.